# Why am i getting "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'default_ipv4'"

Tags: ansible-2.x, ansible-facts, ansible-template

lhost.j2 file contents:

```
{% for host in groups['all'] %}
{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_facts']['default_ipv4'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

test.yaml

```
---
- name: Generate /etc/hosts/ file
  hosts: ansible1
  tasks:
    - name: create /etc/hosts on all hosts
      file:
        path: /etc/hosts_test
        state: touch
    - name: all hosts to be added to /etc/hosts
      template:
        src: lhosts.j2
        dest: /etc/hosts_test
```

error : **"AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'default_ipv4'"**

```
TASK [all hosts to be added to /etc/hosts] *********************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'default_ipv4'
fatal: [ansible1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'default_ipv4'"}
```

Here is the result of `ip r` and `ip a` on target ansible1.

```
[mukesh@ansible1 ~]$ ip r
default via 192.168.122.1 dev enp1s0 proto static metric 100 
192.168.122.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.101 metric 100 
[mukesh@ansible1 ~]$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:0f:0a:e4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.101/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global noprefixroute enp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe0f:ae4/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
[mukesh@ansible1 ~]$
```

Answer (score 1):

To Solve this issue you need first collect all the facts of all nodes to make this work.
your hosts.j2(template) file should look like this

```
{% for host in groups['all'] %}

{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_facts']['default_ipv4']['address'] }} {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_facts']['fqdn'] }} {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_facts']['hostname'] }}

{% endfor %}
```

and the YAML file that you are going to run as a ansible playbook should look like this

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:[]

- hosts: all
  tasks: 
    - template:
        src: "/root/ansible/hosts.j2"
        dest: "/etc/myhosts"
```

As you can see the first two lines of the YAML code will collect all the facts that will be used by the below task. And make sure that all the nodes should be active and ansible ping should give pong for all the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `default_ipv4` try `ansible_default_ipv4` it is a correct ansiblefact variable.